# SVG straight line animation

Tags: svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have two lines red and blue, where blue line moves along the red line.
I want the blue line to move up and down across the red line.Here it is moving only upwards.
Below is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>

</head>
<body>
 <svg height="210" width="500">
 <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
 <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 153);stroke-width:2">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      from="200 200"
      to="-150 -150"
      begin="0s"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
 </line>
 </svg>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>

</head>
<body>
 <svg height="210" width="500">
 <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
 <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 153);stroke-width:2">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      values="200 200;-150 -150;200 200"
      begin="0s"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
 </line>
 </svg>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the x y coordinates and values for different resolutions dynamically using css or jquery... ?I found only strokes could be changed dynamically...

Comment: With css alone, no. With jquery possibly. Ask a separate question amd someone may provide an answer.

Comment: You can use `$( window ).height()` `> / < / =` to check and set the height and width of svg and  co-ordinates accordingly.